# Need to parse nginx access.log by minute, chunks for statistics - is there better way?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, nginx

I need to collect current data from the nginx access.log every minute to monitor amount of requests and errors. It's nginx's *frontend* log - with **a lot** of requests. It's formatted, rotated, then archived every hour.

So — requests per minute and various errors per minute  — how to parse that I know  — but how to get 1 minute worth of logs?

I am trying to `timeout 60s tail -f /var/log/veryfastmovingaccess.log >> 60s_log.tmp`
Then awk parses tmp, cleans it, restarts tail.
Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off looking at a proper monitor infrastructure, but a quick-n-dirty solution for nginx may be to use [ngxtop](https://github.com/lebinh/ngxtop). It will probably also be a good starting point for any custom monitoring you want to do.

In response to your original question, see also [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/53699/continuosly-monitor-logs-with-tail-that-are-occasionally-rotated?rq=1) on Server Fault.

Comment: Got some more info into the question.